# any advantage to upgrade to 64bit excel VBA?

Tags: vba, 64-bit

Currently I am using a 32bit windows 7 and 32 bit excel 2007 as I have written a few programs in VBA. I am running some memory program as my programs are getting quite large, I would benefit if I can get pass the 4GB ram limit of a 32bit system. However I was worry about compatibility and support if I upgrade to 64 bit version. Most code I found on net on VBA are still 32 bit and I am unsure if there are any real advantages if I upgrade to a 64bit excel 2010 in terms of speed and memory. Can someone points me to the right direction please?

Comment: "Office 64-bit is optimized for advanced data analysis scenarios" for compatibilty issues see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264421.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I've yet to see anything from MS suggesting that your VBA code will be able to access more memory in the 64-bit version; they do promise that you can create larger spreadsheets in Excel.

If your existing 32-bit code makes no Windows API calls and uses no ActiveX controls (other than those that ship with the 64-bit version of Office) or makes no calls to third-party 32-bit DLLs, it should be completely compatible.   WinAPI code will need to be modified (Remou's link explains all of that).